# NSThread High CPU usage

Tags: ios7, core-audio, nsthread

Im trying to using a continually running thread to perform tasks at a high rate in my app.
In this app I have a list of 1000 or so time stamps. I poll them until it's their time and then instruct an ausampler to play.

The problem I have is that I seem to fundamentally not understand how NSThread Works. In the simple example below the cpu shoots up to 100% despite no tasks being run.

In what way I am using NSThread incorrectly?
What would be a better way to create a a very fast polling mechanism that doesnt hog the cpu?

```
myThread =[[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(test) object:Nil];
            [audioThread setThreadPriority:0];
            [audioThread start];


-(void)test

{
    while(mycondition)

{

   // do my work
  // cpu == 100%
}

}
```

Comment: the while loop blocks the main runloop... what you should look into is the [concurrent programming guide of Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). To help you better, more details are necessary.

Comment: Thats really weird. I checked for [NSThread isMainThread] in the while loop and it returns NO.

Comment: You can send events to the AUSampler within it's render callback. This removes having to manage any threads and you can get sample accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to find the minimum interval between sampler fire times (based on bpm/ resolution) and make the thread sleep for that amount.